# angular2 - image rendering not working

Tags: angular

I have a strange problem in my application:

The CSS and JS files included in **index.html** page are **rendered properly**.

Instead the **image are not loaded**, I don't know why.

Css/Js and Image are under the same folder **distAdminLte2** that is so composed :

```
├───css
│   
├───img
│   
└───js
```

this is how I reference the files in **index.html** file:

## Css / Js

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/distAdminLte2/css/AdminLTE.min.css">

<script src="/assets/plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
```

## Image

```
<img src="/assets/distAdminLte2/img/icon-user.png">
```

This instead is a portion of the **index.html** file: it apply the css/js ( I can navigate throug them ) but it doesn't load the image:

## index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Reporting App</title>
  <base href="/">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/distAdminLte2/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
</head>

<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">

  <app-root> 
    <div class="wrapper">Loading...</div>
  </app-root>

  <script src="/assets/plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
 <img src="/assets/distAdminLte2/img/icon-user.png"><br>
</body>

</html>
```

Notice that the `<base href="/">` is set to '/' .

I need to let the image working also for a build.

Thanks to support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by changing the index.html of dist

from

```
<base href="/">
```

to

```
<base href="">
```

Images now loads properly